# About TLB entries and Page table entries

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, tlb

From a website about TLB: (https://www.bottomupcs.com/virtual_memory_hardware.xhtml#other-page-related-faults):

For the following parts I highlighted:

**1**: Is the format of TLB entries the same as PTE(page table entries)? And it's not clear
the "the page" in **the page can be marked as** mean TLB entry or PTE?

**2**: For "the pages" in **go through all the pages**, are they TLB entries or PTEs?

**3**: Why it's **moved out of** not "moved into"?

**4**: Is that the order is (1)set the two bits (2)put into TLB, or the converse?

> There are two other important faults that the TLB can generally generate which help to mange accessed and dirty pages. Each page generally contains an attribute in the form of a single bit which flags if the page has been accessed or is dirty.
>
> An accessed page is simply any page that has been accessed. **<sup>1</sup>When a page translation is initially loaded into the TLB the page can be marked as having been accessed** (else why were you loading it in?[19])
>
> **<sup>2</sup>The operating system can periodically go through all the pages and clear the accessed bit to get an idea of what pages are currently in use**. When system memory becomes full and it comes time for the operating system to choose pages to be swapped out to disk, obviously those pages whose accessed bit has not been reset are the best candidates for removal, because they have not been used the longest.
>
> A dirty page is one that has data written to it, and so does not match any data already on disk. For example, if a page is loaded in from swap and then written to by a process, **<sup>3</sup>before it can be moved out of swap** it needs to have its on disk copy updated. A page that is clean has had no changes, so we do not need the overhead of copying the page back to disk.
>
> Both are similar in that they help the operating system to manage pages. The general concept is that a page has two extra bits; the dirty bit and the accessed bit. **<sup>4</sup>When the page is put into the TLB, these bits are set to indicate that the CPU should raise a fault.**
>
> When a process tries to reference memory, the hardware does the usual translation process. However, it also does an extra check to see if the accessed flag is not set. If so, it raises a fault to the operating system, which should set the bit and allow the process to continue. Similarly if the hardware detects that it is writing to a page that does not have the dirty bit set, it will raise a fault for the operating system to mark the page as dirty.

Comment: Yes, "before it can be moved out of swap" is worded wrong.  It's talking about copying a dirty page *to* swap space again.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure if the TLB is allowed to write-back cache modifications to the Accessed and Dirty bits of a PTE, or if those modifications to memory have to (logically) become visible right away, like the result of a store instruction.  I'd guess right away.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Could it mean that if another process want to use that page (so swap out), the dirty page has to be written back first?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.  That interpretation requires "it" to be a pronoun for some other page you want to swap in.  But that doesn't make any sense because that subject hasn't been introduced anywhere in that paragraph, so "it" is clearly still the dirty page in question.  The whole point of having a dirty bit is to indicate that the copy on disk is out of sync with the copy in memory (for memory mapped files or for pages with swap as their backing store).  "moved out of swap" sounds like freeing the disk page, not freeing the RAM page, so it's backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest ignoring that link as a source. It is highly confusing. I do not see any mention of a specific implementation but it is clearly describing one.

In any rationally designed processor, the TLB is completely transparent to programmers (even systems programmers). It is entirely a piece of hardware.

> 1: Is the format of TLB entries the same as PTE(page table entries)?

A programmer never sees TLB entries. They could have the same format as PTEs. They might not.

> 2: For "the pages" in go through all the pages, are they TLB entries or PTEs?

Programmers have no access to TLB entries. They have to refer to PTEs.

> 3: Why it's moved out of not "moved into"?

Probably but there seems to be a lot of confusion in your link.

> 4: Is that the order is (1)set the two bits (2)put into TLB, or the converse?

This is describing some specific, unnamed implementation. Most processors have a dirty bit but not all have an accessed bit.

Comment: "completely transparent" is an overstatement.  In most architectures, you have to explicitly invalidate TLB entries after modifying a PTE.  On x86, the relevant instruction is [`invlpg`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INVLPG.html), and is needed if the PTE was previous valid, even if it could only have been speculatively cached.  But x86 ISA rules prevent negative caching, so you can make an invalid PTE valid without `invlpg`.  (If you're saying the TLB is transparent for Accessed and Dirty bits, then yeah I think that's true.  But what you wrote sounds like a stronger claim.)

Comment: Intel's and ARM are the only processors that I can think of that have instructions that manage the TLB.

Comment: PowerPC has `tlbie` (TLB invalide entry) and `tlbia` (invalidate all).  http://www.csit-sun.pub.ro/~cpop/Documentatie_SMP/Motorola_PowerPC/PowerPc/GenInfo/pemch7.pdf.  This is normal; if you have paging, you normally have manual TLB invalidation.  Some ISAs have purely software-managed TLB entries (no HW page walker, so SW has to set TLB entries in a kernel-provided TLB-miss handler function).  MIPS was like this, for example.  (Some modern embedded MIPS CPUs might not have paging at all, but I forget if modern MIPS has HW page walking.)

Comment: Can you name an ISA that has paging + TLBs but doesn't require the kernel to manually invalidate entries after changing page tables?  i.e. that snoops stores to the page table to maintain coherency automatically?

Comment: If VAX doesn't have an instruction to invalidate a TLB entry, I think that means it can only flush the whole buffer by installing a new page table (or re-installing the current one).  Like x86 `mov cr3, reg`. 
 https://www.cs.rice.edu/~alc/comp521/Papers/p113-black.pdf cites VAX as one ISA where buffer flushes are expensive.  If PTE writes were snooped even across cores in a multiprocessor, Mach on VAX could just use that without needing to do anything special for TLB shootdowns.

Comment: Definitely the usual design is for the OS to have to invalidate the TLB when changing a PTE.  e.g. [these generic intro to paging/TLB slides from a university course](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/os/slides/12-pagetable.pdf) say *"when OS changes protection bits in a PTE, it needs to invalidate the PTE if it is in the TLB"*.  (And BTW, VAX is old and unusual.  It pages the page-table instead of just using multi-level page tables like modern CPUs.)